# How to accept a valid private CA root certificate for a WCF service in a .NET Core client?

Tags: wcf, ssl, .net-core, root-certificate

I have a .NET Core 3 web service that consumes a third-party WCF service. The service is hosted on a server that's using a private root certificate which I need to trust, but only if it's valid otherwise (not expired and has valid signatures).

I am using Azure App Services. Azure does not support custom certificate authorities in their lower-tier service plans. The Isolated plan supports it, but it is 5x more expensive and would be overkill for the single purpose of trusting a root certificate.

I was looking for workarounds. There are solutions for HttpClient using `HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`. However, the WCF reference does not use HttpClient; it uses an autogenerated client code based on ClientBase.

Then there are some older solutions for completely disabling certificate validation in .NET using `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` but that is not supported in .NET Core. And even if it was, I don't want to completely disable the validation; I want it to still validate everything, except that it should trust the specific root certificate.

Is there any way to feed the trusted root certificate into a ClientBase-based client, or to intercept its validation mechanism but without introducing serious security holes? I wouldn't want to start blindly accepting any random certificate.

Comment: You may take a look at this link:[configure TLS mutual authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth).

Comment: @Jiayao  That is for client certificates. In my case, the client certificate is working fine, but the server certificate is not being accepted because of missing trust.

Comment: Maybe you can add the x509 certificate authentication in server-side.

Comment: @Jiayao The server does not belong to me. It belongs to another third-party organization. And the problem is not with x509 certificate, it's with their HTTPS certificate - they have a privately generated certificate that .Net does not trust.